# Boostraping UDP Server for Netty 4.0?

Tags: netty

Can someone bootstrap me with a UDP Server for Netty 4.0? i see plenty of 3.x examples, but no sign of 4.x even at netty source example. (note I am very new to Netty )

Basically, it is the example at https://netty.io/Documentation/New+and+Noteworthy#HNewbootstrapAPI but for UDP instead. Help is much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read the FAQ - particularly regarding the type of questions welcome here.  This one might be better on one of the other Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: This is a perfectly fine question for SO.

Comment: Check this project, looks like they are using Netty 4 and UDP: https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server/blob/netty4/nadron/src/main/java/io/nadron/handlers/netty/UDPUpstreamHandler.java

Answer (score 2):

Package `netty-example` includes classes [`QuoteOfTheMomentServer`](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/qotm/QuoteOfTheMomentServer.java), [`QuoteOfTheMomentServerHandler`](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/qotm/QuoteOfTheMomentServerHandler.java), [`QuoteOfTheMomentClient`](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/qotm/QuoteOfTheMomentClient.java) and [`QuoteOfTheMomentClientHandler`](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/qotm/QuoteOfTheMomentClientHandler.java). These demonstrate how to create a simple UDP server.

I am pasting the code as it exists in *Netty 4.1.24*. I suggest to find these classes for the version of Netty that you are using.

QuoteOfTheMomentServer:

```
public final class QuoteOfTheMomentServer {

private static final int PORT = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("port", "7686"));

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(group)
         .channel(NioDatagramChannel.class)
         .option(ChannelOption.SO_BROADCAST, true)
         .handler(new QuoteOfTheMomentServerHandler());

        b.bind(PORT).sync().channel().closeFuture().await();
    } finally {
        group.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
}
```

QuoteOfTheMomentServerHandler:

```
public class QuoteOfTheMomentServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<DatagramPacket> {

private static final Random random = new Random();

// Quotes from Mohandas K. Gandhi:
private static final String[] quotes = {
    "Where there is love there is life.",
    "First they ignore you, then they laugh at you, then they fight you, then you win.",
    "Be the change you want to see in the world.",
    "The weak can never forgive. Forgiveness is the attribute of the strong.",
};

private static String nextQuote() {
    int quoteId;
    synchronized (random) {
        quoteId = random.nextInt(quotes.length);
    }
    return quotes[quoteId];
}

@Override
public void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramPacket packet) throws Exception {
    System.err.println(packet);
    if ("QOTM?".equals(packet.content().toString(CharsetUtil.UTF_8))) {
        ctx.write(new DatagramPacket(
                Unpooled.copiedBuffer("QOTM: " + nextQuote(), CharsetUtil.UTF_8), packet.sender()));
    }
}

@Override
public void channelReadComplete(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
    ctx.flush();
}

@Override
public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) {
    cause.printStackTrace();
    // We don't close the channel because we can keep serving requests.
}
}
```

Comment: Hi @aleksandr-dubinsky , QuoteOfTheMomentServer uses Bootstrap class and it does not use ServerBootstrap. If I use ServerBootstrap, then NioDatagramChannel mentioned in the example cannot be used as it does not extend from ServerChannel. Could you please clarify why the example uses Bootstrap class which is typically used in a client and not on server? I understand that the example behaves like a server though.

Comment: I think this answers my question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37681245/1756069 Please correct me if I  am wrong.